# After uninstall php from ubuntu and reinstalling it. My web site stopped work.

Tags: server, php

I'm running an Ubuntu server, and I got a problem with an SAP extension for php.

I decided to uninstall php and reinstall it but now nothing works at all.

This how I installed  php :

```
./configure
make
apt-get install checkinstall
checkinstall
```

the installation works fine, but I don't understand why nothing works anymore.

Thanks in advanced for your help

Comment: ?. the code you used to install php is for compiling an app? and making a deb file(i think) last command should be "make install" to install it on your system! but you can install php like so "sudo apt-get install php5"(i think i am on a windows machine right now. at the top of my head, thats the command used to install php) without the need for compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you used to install php is for compiling software? and making a `.deb` file!

The last command should be `sudo make install` to install it on your system! instead of

> apt-get install checkinstall checkinstall

The right way to install an app, is so `sudo apt-get install php5` without the need for compiling.

---

The bit of standard commands for compiling are.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

`checkinstall` is for making `.deb` files!